# Extract AOI from LAS Dataset into a single las file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, lidar, las

I am looking for a way to take a polygon (AOI) and extract a .las file from an las dataset. Currently, when I use the tool Extract LAS, the output is multiple tiles. Is there a way to either a) get the tool to output only one single .las tile or b) merge togther multiple .las files into a single .las file?

[image: These are the input and output files that I am working with.]

Comment: Add a screenshot to show the input, and the output you recieved.

Comment: @YogeshChavan I just added a picture of the files I am looking at

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your LAS Dataset is made up of multiple files and when you extract using your extents, it falls between two different .las files in the dataset and clips two of the .las that were ingested. However, it should produce a new single LAS dataset, but if you require .las and not .lasd, you should be able to merge the output .las using LASTools. You can also try merging using CloudCompare or QT Modeler if you have it.